# Generating account statement in C# and saving it as image

Tags: c#, image, dynamically-generated

I am developing a C# application that will send customers account statement as inline image in email.

Is it possible to create an account statement in image form in C#? This is standard statement with logo on top and some data in tabular format.

Sample statement is given below.

[Account Statement from WikiPedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/BankStatementChequing.png)

Comment: you may use reporting components like Stimulsoft and then export the result to an image

Comment: It is possible. You can use Bitmap class and manually render all that things. But it's a pretty big deal. The simplest way is to use 3rd party components like MS ReportViewer. See method [LocalReport.Render](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251837.aspx). Moreover, you can specify query and create a report template (.rdlc) using result schema.

Comment: So I can create it in RDLC and then convert to image for e.g. JPG etc?